# Can't resolve all parameters for MyService in /tmp/src/my.service.ts: (?). This will become an error in Angular v6.x

Tags: angular

Today I faced a compiler error when upgrading from Angular 5 to Angular 6, I was getting the following error after running `ng build`:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for MyService in /tmp/src/my.service.ts: (?). This will become an error in Angular v6.x
```

In the service it looked similar to this (I've simplified for the example):

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService<T> {
    constructor(temp: T = null) {
    }
}
```

I've added how I solved this problem below, but please let me know if there is a better way because I might not have done it to follow best practices.

Answer (score 1):

The reason I had this problem:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for MyService in /tmp/src/my.service.ts: (?). This will become an error in Angular v6.x
```

was because I was injecting a service that had things in the constructor that were not injected. So the first step in fixing up the problem was to remove the `@Injectable()` decorator.

If you cannot remove the `@Injectable()` decorator because the service must be injectable, then you need to ensure that the parameters in the constructor can be injected or resolved correctly by the compiler.